# GMF eclipse exception

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gmf

I'm trying to produce the gmf editor from an ecore meta-model. I'm following mainly [this tutorial](http://www.rcp-vision.com/?p=1476&lang=en). I have getting the below error when I'm trying to run the gmf as Eclipse application.

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_21
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -application test.diagram.TestApplication
Command-line arguments:  -application test.diagram.TestApplication -data C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse epsilon\workspace/../runtime-test.diagram.TestApplication -dev file:C:/Program Files (x86)/eclipse epsilon/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/test.diagram.TestApplication/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.printing.render 4 0 2014-08-03 13:42:06.118
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.printing.render [33]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.draw2d.ui.render.awt; bundle-version="[1.2.0,2.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.draw2d.ui.render.awt; bundle-version="1.8.0.201406111639"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.draw2d.ui.render.awt [81]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.batik.ext.awt; bundle-version="[1.6.0,1.7.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.batik.ext.awt; bundle-version="1.6.0.v201011041432"
              org.apache.batik.ext.awt [7]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.batik.util; bundle-version="[1.6.0,1.7.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Which Eclipse version and bundle did you download? In the RCP Vision tutorials they used Eclipse Juno Modeling, if I remember correct.

Comment: I have tried with Eclipse Luna and Epsilon.

Comment: The line "Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.batik.util; bundle-version="[1.6.0,1.7.0)" " indicates, that your installation lacks that bundle. You can find out, by checking "Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Plugins" for the missing package. If it isn't there, you should try the Eclipse distribution that was used by the creator of the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with conflicting dependencies in Eclipse Luna SR1. The solution I found for this problem is the following:

- Go to the MANIFEST.MF of your diagram project and remove the dependency to: `org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.render`

This removes your error but another error can appear if you are using Java 7. The problem is in the `org.eclipse.jdt.annotation 2.x` library which requires Java 8. To solve this you need to:

- Go to Run -> Configurations
- Select the tab "Plug-ins"
- Choose "plug-ins selected below only" next to "Launch with"
- Click "Deselect all"
- Click "Add required plugins" (for this button to be enabled the search box needs to be empty)
- Uncheck `org.eclipse.jdt.annotation 2.x`
- Check `org.eclipse.jdt.annotation 1.x`
- Apply and run.

The GMF editor can be launched. There will be an exception written to the console because of the missing dependency, but it doesn't seem to make a difference (unless for me)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the cause was that both versions 1.6 and 1.7 of Apache Batik were enabled on launch. Based on Edumundos solution, this solved my problem:

In the run configuration plugins tab, search for `batik`. There are multiple plugins with the same name but different versions. Disable all that are version 1.6.